# Can I take a lot of luggage with me on NS inter city train from Schiphol to Groningen

Tags: trains, public-transport, netherlands

I will be reaching Schiphol airport on a Monday at around 13:30 in August. I will have two medium-sized trolley bags and one backpack. Is there any provision to store luggage on the train or should I look out for any particular compartment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You should be fine.**

Early afternoon is not the busiest time in Dutch trains, so there should be plenty of room on the train for both you and your bags. I would recommend taking the direct hourly train from Schiphol all the way to Groningen (departs every x:04), as otherwise you would have to change trains at Zwolle, which sounds like unnecessary hassle just to save half an hour.

Most likely, this will be an [ICM train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NS_Intercity_Materieel) (also known as "koploper"), which is a good thing. These are fairly normal single-decker trains, so you won't have to deal with another set of stairs as in the double-decker variety common on other routes ([VIRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NS_VIRM) or  [DDZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NS_DD-AR)).

There is no dedicated luggage compartment but (this being the Netherlands) there is quite a lot of room for bikes which shouldn't be full this time of the day, so you can put your bags there. Alternatively, you can take your bags inside the seating compartment and place them either in the overhead luggage racks (if they fit and aren't too heavy to lift) or between the backs of two seats facing the opposite way (this might be only possible in the double-deckers, I'm not sure). [The interior of an ICM looks like this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Interieur_2e_klasse_ICMm.JPG#/media/File:Interieur_2e_klasse_ICMm.JPG).

Note however that formally speaking, your bags shouldn't exceed [85 centimeters in any dimension](https://www.ns.nl/reisinformatie/bagage). I've never seen anyone measuring bags,  so this shouldn't be an issue in practice, but if your bag is much bigger than the limit, make extra sure it doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Do stay with your luggage. It does not happen often but when someone walks of with your luggage you are not happy. In many trains you can bring luggage in the seating parts of the train.

Comment: @Willeke Oh yes, absolutely. I kinda assumed that keeping a close watch on your belongings is a given.

Comment: (+1) It should be added that generally speaking Dutch trains, including ICM, are not designed to accomodate luggage for a long-distance trip. The best place to put a middle-sized suitcase in those is under seats facing in different directions (next to a 4-seat group, like those in the foreground in your picture). Failing that, the OP only choice is to block a row of seat or, indeed, a bike compartment.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, that's what I meant by "between the backs of two seats facing the opposite way", but I'm not entirely sure how common that arrangement is on ICM. I rarely ride those, and as far as I can remember they're mostly half of the seats facing one way, a table in the middle, then half of the seats facing the other way.

Comment: There is space between seats that allow you to put one or two big coffers if it is the double decker

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yes, that's what I'm completely sure of. I'm just not sure if the same applies to the single-deck ICM.

Comment: Neither the old style, nor the refurbished ICMs have back to back seats like the VIRM (double decker) has. Most seats are coach style, with only one vis-a-vis set on each side of a carriage. [Wikipedia has images of the seats](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercitymaterieel)

Comment: Had no problems with similar amount of luggage doing that in 2019 in early September. Was very relaxed.

Comment: Depending on the actual train and the size of the cases, you might be able to store them under the seats. Not all fit but it is a way that is mostly forgotten. Dutch trains do not have luggage areas and most people travel with relatively little which fits in the rack above the seats.